# How to hardwire keyword to search on ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

I am writing a React app that searches movies on a database. However, instead of doing an open search, I want to set search fields in different pages for different subjects. I would like to hardwire the search so the user forcefully needs to add a keyword to their search (i.e. "war", if the search was only to allow any term plus "war" withing a "war" page).

The first `const` below is the query that will use user input to perform the search; the second, creates the state for movies. The const `url` is the search itself:

```
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  const searchMovies = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const url = `https://api.site.com/3/search/movie?api_key=[KEY]&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&include_adult=true`;
```

How could I create a query to have a specific keyword adde by default?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain a little more ?

Comment: Sure @RohitSingh: the search above retrieves data from a movie database. It's an open query: if I want to look for movies like "Jurassic Park", it will bring all results with this keyword. However, I want that, on a specific page, narrow down the search to contain "zombies" as a keyword, no matter what you are searching (even if you leave the field blank). If someone looks for "pain" on this page, the query will be "pain" + "zombies". Is that clear?

Answer (score 0):

you could pass a prop `theme` to Search Component. at url you would write `...query=${props.theme+query}`.

at every page new change you would call SetTheme with proper theme and pass down state to Input as props.